# Area routing in ASP.NET Core 5.0

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Using ASP.NET Core 5.0 MVC, the application is using an area named `Counselor` with a `HomeController` and `Index` action.

[image: ,]

One link is added in `Layout.cshtml` to counselor.

[image]

Also, the endpoint is already added the endpoint in Startup.cs

[image]

**The problem:**

The link created is wrong (`localhost:44308/?area=Counselor`) but it should be `localhost:44308/Counselor/Home/Index`

[image]

Comment: Here is an [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-5.0),I test with the settings of you,and it can work.If you try to refresh your page in browser,will it change?

Answer (score 1):

Since I had this problem today too, this is how I solved the problem:

1. Make sure you have SSL enabled in your project settings (I do not know why it should be enabled) [see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtSiX.png).
2. Try this code in Startup.cs:

```
    endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
        name: "Counselor",
        areaName: "Counselor ",
        pattern: "Counselor/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

4. Then don't forget to add [Area("Counselor")] at the beginning of the controller like this:

```
    namespace Project.Controllers
    {
        [Area("Counselor")]
        public class HomeController : Controller
        {
```